# Ordered (n choose p) binary encoding and decoding

Tags: python, encoding, binary, combinatorics

I want to 'impose' order on (n choose p) binary and be able to encode/decode items.

Below you can see an example of p=2. For p > 2 it will need more loops.
BTW this function is just illustration on ONE specific order, it can be different one
just have to exhaust all combinations.

What I'm after is the encode/decode !!

It will be even better if it uses the INDEX value instead of bitarray i.e. 10100 => (3,5)

```
import numpy as np

#should exhaust all (n choose p) possibilities
def order(p=2,n=4) :
  p = 0
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
      v = np.zeros(n,dtype=int)
      v[i]=1; v[j]=1; p+=1
      print(f'pos:{p} {v}')
      
def encode(pos,p=2,n=4):
  pass #should return val at pos

def decode(value,p=2,n=4):
  pass #should return  pos of val
 
      
order(n=4)
print()
order(n=5)

-----

pos:1 [1 1 0 0]
pos:2 [1 0 1 0]
pos:3 [1 0 0 1]
pos:4 [0 1 1 0]
pos:5 [0 1 0 1]
pos:6 [0 0 1 1]

pos:1 [1 1 0 0 0]
pos:2 [1 0 1 0 0]
pos:3 [1 0 0 1 0]
pos:4 [1 0 0 0 1]
pos:5 [0 1 1 0 0]
pos:6 [0 1 0 1 0]
pos:7 [0 1 0 0 1]
pos:8 [0 0 1 1 0]
pos:9 [0 0 1 0 1]
pos:10 [0 0 0 1 1]
```

---

seems legit :

```
In [36]: [nth_combination(range(10),3,i) for i in range(10)]                                                                                                                 
Out[36]: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 1, 5), (0, 1, 6), (0, 1, 7), (0, 1, 8), (0, 1, 9), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4)]



In [6]: [nth_combination(range(1000),5,i) for i in range(100000,100010)]                                                                                                     
Out[6]: 
[(0, 1, 2, 108, 989),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 990),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 991),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 992),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 993),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 994),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 995),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 996),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 997),
 (0, 1, 2, 108, 998)]

In [7]: combination_index((0,1,2,108,990),range(1000))                                                                                                                       
Out[7]: 100001
```

Comment: Do you mean like `more_itertools.nth_combination` and `more_itertools.combination_index`?

Comment: will check..  but probably should not relay on iterable, cause it may blow on (1000 10) or bigger

Comment: Why would that "blow" (whatever that means)?

Comment: blow ~~ will be very slow because it have to call next()  million times .... it should be direct calculation

Comment: I think you misunderstood what it does.

Comment: possible.. the docs are  sketchy..will look the source code .. u are right " computes the subsequence at sort position index directly, without computing the previous subsequences"

Answer (score 1):

Below is a recursive implementation of encoding / decoding. I want to issue two caveats:

If you were to encode/decode outrageously large values, you could run into `RecursionDepthExceeded` exceptions, as with most recursion. However, this will require insanely large input values.

Secondly, this can be a lot slower than it needs to be, due to the list concatenation (used for simplicity). If performance is a concern, you should pass an accumulator, and append to the list rather than concatenating + forming new lists constantly. At that point, probably convert the recursion into an iterative loop as well.

```py
from math import comb


def encode(pos, n, p):
    if p == n:
        return [1] * n
    if p == 0:
        return [0] * n

    if pos < comb(n-1, p-1):
        return [1] + encode(pos, n-1, p-1)
    else:
        return [0] + encode(pos - comb(n-1, p-1), n-1, p)

def decode(value, n, p):
    if all(value):
        return 0
    if not any(value):
        return 0

    head, *tail = value
    if head == 1:
        return decode(tail, n-1, p-1)
    else:
        return comb(n-1, p-1) + decode(tail, n-1, p)
```

Example:

```py
for i in range(6):
    e = encode(i, 4, 2)
    d = decode(e, 4, 2)
    print(i, e, i == d)
```

Output:

```
0 [1, 1, 0, 0] True
1 [1, 0, 1, 0] True
2 [1, 0, 0, 1] True
3 [0, 1, 1, 0] True
4 [0, 1, 0, 1] True
5 [0, 0, 1, 1] True
```